# Appflood ads not showing on iOS

Tags: ios, ads

I am using Appflood for my next game . I am developing it in Unity. So want to integrate it for both Android and iOS . For Android it works perfectly but for iOS it get stuck at "Loading view" forever.

steps I have double verified :-

1> Key and secret are same as in DashBoard.

2> Status of app is Approved on DashBoard.

3> Internet Connection is up.

Now Do I need to  have it submit to the app store before Ads begin to show ? according to this [FAQ](http://appflood.com/a/faqs#p1) it has to be ! but then why Android ads are showing up ?

PS: It has not even 24 hrs since I created the app on DashBoard.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to hear you've been having problems with AppFlood SDK. At the point you mentioned, if the SDK was properly integrated you could see the ads showing in your app before you submit it to the app store.

We can double check the integration for you, so why don't you first send me email on: weronika@papayamobile.com and we'll try to figure it out :)

Comment: hey weronika ,  problem is solved , I mailed you , jun and francis if you remember :)